# How does data get through a router if there is no portforwarding set on the router

Tags: networking, server-administration

more over how does the router distinguish each packet between the multiple connected users. Why does the router just not ignore all request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most home routes use [one-to-many NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#One-to-many_NAT). That means that the router associates a local IP address and a port to a port in the router and forwards tha packets through there.

This image explains it:

[image: A router performing one-to-many NAT]

When the server responds to the client, it will send packets to `145.12.131.7, 6282` and the router will forward them to `192.168.100.3, 3855`.

Comment: thanks, So you could say it adds a temporary port forward and passes that info on to the server side.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it answered your question.